# getting model data to a view backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, models, backbone-views

I am trying to understand the relationship between a model and a view. I've tried building a model and view to render that model.

I get the error `Cannot call method 'toJSON' of undefined` which I understand as the actual instance of the model is not being sent to the view.

I feel there is something missing in the initialize of the view?

The Model:

```
var sticky = Backbone.Model.extend({

defaults: {
    title:"",
    content:"",
    created: new Date()

},

initialize: function() {
    console.log("sticky created!");

}

});
```

The View:

```
var stickyView = Backbone.View.extend({

tagName:"div",
className:"sticky-container",

initialize: function() {
    this.render();
    console.log("stickyView created!");
},

render: function() {
    $("#content-view").prepend(this.el);
    var data = this.model.toJSON(); // Error: Cannot call method 'toJSON' of undefined 
    console.log(data);
    var source = $("#sticky-template").html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
    $(this.el).html(template(data));
    return this;
}

});
```

Creating new model and new instance of the view:

```
var Sticky = new sticky({title:"test"});

var StickyView = new stickyView();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to pass your model instance to your view, [Backbone will do the rest](http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor):

> **constructor / initialize** new View([options])
>   There are several special options that, if passed, will be attached directly to
>   the view: model, collection, el, id, className, tagName and
>   attributes.

which means you would create your view like this

```
var StickyView = new stickyView({model: Sticky});
```

And while you're at it, you could pass your compiled template and the DOM node you wish to set as your view element (and remove the `tagName` and `className` from your view definition) to avoid a strict coupling:

```
var stickyView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function(opts) {
        this.template = opts.template;
        this.render();
        console.log("stickyView created!");
    },

    render: function() {
        var data = this.model.toJSON();
        console.log(data);

        this.$el.html(this.template(data));

        return this;
    }

});

var StickyView = new stickyView({
    model: Sticky, 
    el: '#content-view',
    template: Handlebars.compile($("#sticky-template").html())
});
```